# How to store the result of a calculation in a list in SageMath

Tags: sage

I can't figure out how to store the result of a calculation in a List in SageMath.

I have combed the tutorial and help pages, but I can't seem to find this very simple thing. The Pseudocode I want is:

```
Loop through i
    Loop through j
       Loop through k
          Result[i,j,k]=Calculation involving i,j, and k
```

The actual calculation is several lines of if statements and while statements, so I don't think it can be manipulated into the simple form I often see in Sage:

```
Result=[ [i,j,] for i,j in Q]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are some options:

```
sage: R = [100*i + 10*j + k for i in range(2) for j in range(2) for k in range(2)]
sage: R
[0, 1, 10, 11, 100, 101, 110, 111]
```

or

```
R = []
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(2):
        for k in range(2):
            R.append(100*i + 10*j + k)
```

If you actually want something like `Result[i,j,k] = ...`, i.e., with the results indexed by i, j, k, maybe you want a dictionary instead:

```
sage: R = {(i,j,k): 100*i + 10*j + k for i in range(2) for j in range(2) for k in range(2)}
sage: R
{(0, 0, 0): 0,
 (0, 0, 1): 1,
 (0, 1, 0): 10,
 (0, 1, 1): 11,
 (1, 0, 0): 100,
 (1, 0, 1): 101,
 (1, 1, 0): 110,
 (1, 1, 1): 111}
sage: R[1,0,1]
101
```

or with the nested `for` loops, initialize it with `R={}` and then replace the last line in loop with `R[i,j,k] = ...`